# Why is my User defined Function not showing results VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have created a UDF called YRatio(Str). When I use the insert formula for a cell the result appears on the dialog box but inside the cell it shows "=YRatio(C2)"

The result I get is right. But it doesn't appear in the cells.

```
Function YRatio(CellRef As String) As String
Dim Arr() As String
Dim tot As Integer
Dim yyes As Integer
Dim Str As String

Str = CellRef '.Value

Arr() = Split(Str, Chr(10))

For Each Line In Arr
    tot = tot + 1
    If Left(Line, 1) = "Y" Then
        yyes = yyes + 1
    End If
Next
YRatio = CStr(yyes) & "/" & CStr(tot)
End Function
```

Comment: can you post the code for the function please.

Comment: Check if "Show Formulas" is enabled. You can find it on the "Formulas" tab in the ribbon.

Comment: Also, check if the format of the cell is Text instead of Standard

Comment: Have added the code. also all other formulas are showing results, all inbuilt formulas

Comment: Just wondering but... do you even need a custom function? Can you put a sample dataset and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

> inside the cell it shows "=YRatio(C2)"

You need to change the formatting of the cell to `General`. Currently it is formatted as `Text`

Also `Arr() = Split(Str, Chr(10))` in your code should be `Arr() = Split(Range(Str).Value, Chr(10))`.

**Imp Tip**: Avoid using [LINE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/line-inputstatement) and [STR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function) as variables. Use more meaningful names.

Your code can be written as

```
Option Explicit

Function YRatio(CellRef As Range) As String
    Dim Arr() As String
    Dim tot As Long
    Dim yyes As Long
    Dim itm As Variant
    
    Arr() = Split(CellRef.Value2, Chr(10))
    
    For Each itm In Arr
        tot = tot + 1
        If Left(itm, 1) = "Y" Then yyes = yyes + 1
    Next
    YRatio = yyes & "/" & tot
End Function
```

Here I am passing the cell as `Range`.

Now you can type in the cell `=YRatio(C2)` which is formatted as `General` and it will work.

You can use use this version of the code which uses `UBound(Arr)` to get the total elements of the array rather then using `tot = tot + 1`

```
Option Explicit

Function YRatio(CellRef As Range) As String
    Dim Arr() As String
    Dim yyes As Long
    Dim itm As Variant
    
    Arr() = Split(CellRef.Value2, Chr(10))
    
    For Each itm In Arr
        If Left(itm, 1) = "Y" Then yyes = yyes + 1
    Next
    YRatio = yyes & "/" & UBound(Arr)
End Function
```